# How to fix ThemeProvider with React.StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to set up a toggle for dark mode and light mode themes. After eliminating almost everything in the project, I managed to reproduce the issue in a minimal example.

When I use the `React.StrictMode` JSX wrapper, [useful to prevent issues as you develop](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), the theme can be toggled with `ThemeProvider` once, but after that the changes are no longer applied.

Here is a [live code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/theme-swap-example) to play with. Check it out, and hit the toggle dark mode button a few times, and you'll see it never goes back to light mode.

However, if you just remove the `React.StrictMode` tag that encloses everything, the app works as expected:

From this

```
function App() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <ThemeWrapper />
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

To this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContextProvider>
      <ThemeWrapper />
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Any ideas? Is this a react or material-ui bug? Or is there some way to use these differently?

Comment: I too am seeing some odd behavior following this blog post.
https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/05/27/material-ui-theme-switcher-react

Removing <React.StrictMode> solves the issue; but I don't understand why.  StrictMode according to documents is for warning/informational purposes only, it shouldn't really change the behavior of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party but I was having the same problem.

Aparrently Material UI doesn't fully support Strict mode but you can use this function to work around the problem and still have material themes and strict mode.

```
import { unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

And I'm using it like this

```
  const theme = unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme(themeCreator(themeName));

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={setThemeName}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {props.children}
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
```